# iOS - Not all my In-App Purchases are showing up in iTunesConnect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have a rather odd, yet serious, problem, and I haven't been able to find anyone with a similar scenario.

I have an app which has options for three in-app purchases. Inside, `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` method, I send my server a call upon a successful purchase and record it in my database. So I know the exact number of each of the IAPs in real time for my app.

However, when log into **iTunesConnect** and look at the sales, I see a dramatically smaller number for the number of completed in app purchases. For instance, three days ago, my database recorded **150** in app purchases. Yet iTunesConenect only shows a total of **30** completed transactions for that same day.

I am at a loss as to why this could be.

I don't verify the receipts - I chose to not verify them because I really don't care if a small number of people jailbreak their phone and get the IAPs for free. So I suppose this could be the issues, but I really doubt that 120 out of 150 users using my app are using jailbroken phones.

So I'm wondering: is there a delay in the iTunesConnect IAP reporting? Or is it something in my code? (Code below)

```
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        NSLog(@"Transaction: %@\n", transaction.payment.productIdentifier);

        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

                NSLog(@"Processing purchase");
                [_purchasingActivityView setTitle:@"Processing"];

                // show wait view here
                //statusLabel.text = @"Processing...";
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

                //TODO-> Log analytics
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                NSLog(@"Finished purchase: %@\n", transaction.payment.productIdentifier);

                //All Filters were purchased
                if([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseFilterPackALLProductId]) {
                    if ([[ACSimpleKeychain defaultKeychain] storeUsername:@"iapALL"
                                                                 password:nil
                                                               identifier:transaction.transactionIdentifier
                                                               forService:@"myService"]) {
                        [Logger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stored transaction credentials for fall: %@", transaction.transactionIdentifier]];

                            [[WebCallManager sharedManager] sendPurchaseNotice:@"ALL" withDeviceId:[OpenUDID value] withDelegate:nil];
                    }
                    else {
                        [Logger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error storing transaction credentials for fpone & fptwo purchase: %@", transaction.transactionIdentifier]];
                    }
                }

                //Filter Pack ONE was purchased
                else if([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseFilterPackONEProductId]) {
                    if ([[ACSimpleKeychain defaultKeychain] storeUsername:@"iapONE"
                                                                 password:nil
                                                               identifier:transaction.transactionIdentifier
                                                               forService:@"myService"]) {
                        [Logger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stored transaction credentials for fpone purchase: %@", transaction.transactionIdentifier]];
                        [[WebCallManager sharedManager] sendPurchaseNotice:@"ONE" withDeviceId:[OpenUDID value] withDelegate:nil];
                    }
                    else {
                        [Logger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error storing transaction credentials for fpone purchase: %@", transaction.transactionIdentifier]];
                    }
                }

                //Filter Pack TWO was purchased
                else if([transaction.payment.productIdentifier isEqualToString:kInAppPurchaseFilterPackTWOProductId]) {
                    if ([[ACSimpleKeychain defaultKeychain] storeUsername:@"iapTWO"
                                                                 password:nil
                                                               identifier:transaction.transactionIdentifier
                                                               forService:@"myService"]) {
                        [Logger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Stored transaction credentials for fptwo purchase: %@", transaction.transactionIdentifier]];
                        [[WebCallManager sharedManager] sendPurchaseNotice:@"TWO" withDeviceId:[OpenUDID value] withDelegate:nil];
                    }
                    else {
                        [Logger log:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error storing transaction credentials for fptwo purchase: %@", transaction.transactionIdentifier]];
                    }
                }


                [_purchasingActivityView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];

                break;


            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                if(_purchasingActivityView) {
                    [_purchasingActivityView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
                }

                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view here
                NSLog(@"Transation restored\n");
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"Error payment cancelled");
                }
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                // remove wait view here

                [_purchasingActivityView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
                NSLog(@"Purchase Error: %@\n", [[transaction error] description]);

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

From the users point of view, the transactions appear to work perfectly.

Any help/advice would be incredibly appreciated. This is completely bewildering to me.
Thanks!

**EDIT**: I should also mention that I have three IAP products, all of which have been purchased multiple times according to my database records. However ITC, only shows two of them ever having been purchased.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Perhaps there could be a delay? I have no idea... Sometimes I would have 30 purchases one day, but only 20 would be reported. Then the next day I would have 25 purchases, and 35 would be reported. As long as you have the receipt numbers, if you don't get the money Apple owes you, you can back yourself up.

Comment: Did you figure out what was going on? Was it just a delay? I'm having the same issue with my IAPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely jailbroken phones.  On my app I see twice as many fake receipts as real ones.

Answer (score 0):

If a user has purchased your in app purchase before, then removes the app and re-installs the app, they can purchase it again but it will not actually be considered a sale (it will also not show up in iTunes connect). Could this be your disconnect?

Comment: It's doubtful, that would still be a LOT of people uninstalling, then reinstalling. Plus, I store the local IAP receipt in the keychain, so the local record of the purchase will still be there upon reinstalling the app, and the user wouldn't be prompted to repurchase (the features would just be automatically unlocked; I tested this exact case).